# Issue with snippet completion on VS Code 1.65.1

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm writing an extension for VS Code to support code completion and currently facing an issue. It would be great if someone can help me.

Since my VS Code has updated recently to the version 1.65.1, my extension doesn't work properly for the `CompletionItemKind.Snippet`. It seems like the suggestions from VS Code overridden the `choice` of my snippet.

[please check the screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4kub.jpg)

Here is a part of my code

```
return [CompletionItem(
            label=label,
            kind=CompletionItemKind.Snippet,
            filter_text=label,
            sort_text="0",
            insert_text_format=InsertTextFormat.Snippet,
            insert_text='target code = ${1|pandas,spark|}'
        )]
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: So you have your function named `CompletionItem()`?  You should show that too.

Comment: Hi, the `CompletionItem()` is provided by VS Code, you can check it here: https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/specifications/lsp/3.17/specification/#completionItem

Answer (score 0):

Ah my issue has been solved by the new version of VS Code, 1.65.2. Thanks for that.